# Switch statement not taking input

Tags: c++

This program manages student's scores. For some reason that is unknown to me, the switch statements are not working. I personally think it is reading the whitespaces which will hinder it from taking input. Or am I overlooking another problem? I have tried using (" %d", &choice), also cin >>. But it always exits the program no matter what I input.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    int student_number;
    char student_name[10];
    int geography;
    int english;
    int mongolian;
    int sum;
}Student;
Student stud[100];

void menu();
void get_information();
void display();
void search();
void del_information();
int m;
int load();

int main()
{
    menu();
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            void get_information();
            break;
        case 2:
            void search();
            break;
        case 3:
            void del_information();
            break;
        case 4:
            void display();
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void menu()
{
    
    printf("请选择你的功能：");
    printf("1. 输入学生信息 ");
    printf("2. 查询学生信息 ");
    printf("3. 删除学生 ");
        printf("4. 输出所有学生成绩单");
    printf("4. 出口\n ");
        
}

void get_information()
{
    int i;
    printf("请输入学生人数：");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        printf("请输入学号：");
        scanf("%d", &stud[i].student_number);
        printf("请输入姓名：");
        scanf("%s", stud[i].student_name);
        printf("请输入地理成绩：");
        scanf("%d", &stud[i].geography);
        printf("请输入英语成绩：");
        scanf("%d", &stud[i].english);
        printf("请输入蒙古语成绩：");
        scanf("%d", &stud[i].mongolian);
        stud[i].sum=stud[i].english+stud[i].geography+stud[i].mongolian;
    }
}

void display()
{
        int i;
        int po = 0;
        printf("学号\t姓名\t地理\t英语\t蒙语\t总分\n\n");
        for(i = 0; i < m+po; i++)
        {
        printf("%d\t", stud[i].student_number);
        printf("%s\t", stud[i].student_name);
        printf("%d\t\t", stud[i].geography);
        printf("%d\t\t", stud[i].english);
        printf("%d\t\t", stud[i].mongolian);
        printf("%d\n", stud[i].sum);
        
        
        }
        }

        void search ()
        {
        char name[20];
        printf("请输入要寻找的姓名");
        scanf("%s", name);
            int i = 0;
        
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; i++)
        {
        if(!strcmp(name,stud[i].student_name))
        {
        printf("学生的信息是:\n");
        printf("姓名： %s\n", stud[j].student_name);
        printf("学号： %d\n", stud[j].student_number);
        printf("地理成绩： %d\n", stud[j].geography);
        printf("英语成绩： %d\n", stud[j].english);
        printf("蒙语成绩： %d\n", stud[j].mongolian);
            printf("总分：%d\n", stud[j].sum);
        }
        }
        }
        
    void del_information()
        {
        int a;
        int i = 0;
        printf(" 请输入想删除的学生的学号：");
            scanf("%d", &a);
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if (a == stud[i].student_number) {
        for (int k = j; k < 50; k++)
        stud[k] = stud[k+1];
        i--;
        }
        }
        printf("删除成功");
        }
```

Comment: 'the switch statements are not working' Please elaborate on that. The program compiles, you run it, do what ,and then what happens?

Comment: What's up with those function calls in the switch statement? There should be no prepending `void`s.

Comment: Should not `scanf("%d", &i);` be `scanf("%d", &m);`?

Comment: You are declaring functions in the `switch` statement, not executing them.  I recommend reviewing the chapter on calling functions in your favorite C++ reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commenters noted, the function calls should not have `void` before them.  i.e.

```cpp
  switch (choice) {
    case 1:
      get_information();
      break;
    case 2:
      search();
      break;
    case 3:
      del_information();
      break;
    case 4:
      display();
      break;
    case 5:
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
```

You also have a couple other typos.  For example,

```cpp
void get_information() {
  int i;
  printf("请输入学生人数：");
  scanf("%d", &i);
```

should be

```cpp
void get_information() {
  int i;
  printf("请输入学生人数：");
  scanf("%d", &m);
```

Also in `search()` and `del_information()`, I don't think you need `int i = 0;` and the for loops should look more like `for (int j = 0; j <= m; j++) {` assuming `m` is what you're using to keep track of the number of students.

You may consider using a `std::vector<Student> stud` instead of an array `Student stud[100];` to avoid manually managing `m`, the number of students.  Then,

```cpp
#include <vector>

typedef struct { ... } Student;
std::vector<Student> students;

...


void get_information() {
  printf("请输入学生人数：");
  scanf("%d", &m);
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    Student student;
    printf("请输入学号：");
    scanf("%d", &student.student_number);
    ...
    students.push_back(student);
  }
}

void display() {
  
  printf("学号\t姓名\t地理\t英语\t蒙语\t总分\n\n");
  for (Student stud : students) {
    printf("%d\t", stud.student_number);
    ...
  }
}


void search() {
  char name[20];
  printf("请输入要寻找的姓名");
  scanf("%s", name);

  auto stud = std::find_if(
      students.begin(), students.end(),
      [name](Student s) -> bool { return !strcmp(s.student_name, name); });

  printf("学生的信息是:\n");
  printf("姓名： %s\n", stud->student_name);
  ...
}


void del_information() {
  int a;
  printf(" 请输入想删除的学生的学号：");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  students.erase(
      std::remove_if(students.begin(), students.end(),
                     [a](Student s) { return s.student_number == a; }),
      students.end());
  printf("删除成功");
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't other changes be made if using vector, using insert instead of index for example?